# Decryption of file not working for PDF file

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am downloading a PDF file using `AsyncTask` in Android. In the `onPostExecute()` method, I have written a code to encrypt it. The encrypted file is being created in the storage but it is not getting decrypted successfully.

I have checked the encryption and decryption algorithm and it is working fine both ways. I am using `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` to encrypt and decrypt files.

I have already tried encrypting files in a thread. It is still not working.

```
public class EncryptionUtils {

    private final static String ALGO_RANDOM_NUM_GENERATOR = "SHA1PRNG";
    private final static String ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR = "AES";
    private final static int IV_LENGTH = 16;

    private static SecretKey encryptionKey;
    private static SecretKey decryptionKey;
    private static AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec;

    private final static int DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    private final static String ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTER = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void encrypt(SecretKey key, AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {

        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTER);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void decrypt(SecretKey key, AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec,
                               InputStream in, OutputStream out)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTER);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    private static void generateKeys() {
        encryptionKey = null;
        try {
            encryptionKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR).generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] keyData = encryptionKey.getEncoded();

        decryptionKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR);
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
        try {
            SecureRandom.getInstance(ALGO_RANDOM_NUM_GENERATOR).nextBytes(iv);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }
}
```

What I expect to achieve is that when the file is downloaded it should get encrypted successfully and get saved in the internal storage. And when I wish, i could decrypt it back anytime.

**EDIT:**
I am using the `EncryptionUtils` class like this...

```
generateKeys();
final File inputFile = new File(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_NAME + File.separator + pdfSlug + ".pdf");
final File encFile = new File(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_NAME + File.separator +  "enc_file.enc");
try {
EncryptionUtils.encrypt(encryptionKey, paramSpec, new FileInputStream(inputFile), new FileOutputStream(encFile));

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the code of how I am using the encryption class

Comment: Just try your code on a pdf file that is already on the device.

Comment: You should make a function EncryptionUtils.encryptFile(String srcPath, String destPath).

Comment: @blackapps i have tried it. It works fine. The file which is already on deviec encrypts and decrypts correctly.

Comment: Have you compared the sizes of the two encrypted files? Are they equal? Every byte counts.

Comment: @blackapps i dont understand your second comment

Comment: @blackapps yes the size of the files are same. exactly

Comment: So encrypting while downloading and encrypting from file results in encrypted files with equal size. Then what is different in these files? Or what did you do different while encrypting?

Comment: @blackapps i am sorry for not being clear enough, but I am not encrypting the file while downloading. Encryption process starts when the file is downloaded, that is in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: It should not make any difference if you encrypt a file in onPostExecute() or afterwards.